# Duplicate whole project and rename

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project I am using **Xcode version 9.4** and **Swift version 4.1**.

I am creating a application in my main language, and I am thinking about creating the same application in English, but I want this to be a different project. How can I copy/duplicate the old project, and rename everything to the new name in the new project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of your original target, which will allow you to create a separate app with same business (code) logic and different Bundle ID, Signing certificates, Splash Screen, the project specific links.

Here are steps to create duplicate target:

1. Select Your Project Target (Project ► General ► Select Target)
2. Right Click on Project Target
3. Select `Duplicate` (Menu popover will provide your option to create a duplicate target)

[image]

4. Here is duplicate copy of your target, that you can distribute as a New app with same business logic.

[image]

Your future updates/changes in code will effect on both target, if your source code file has assigned both targets.

Comment: No sure if this is what I need. I am going to release this as two different applications in iTunes Connect, so all the logic will be the same, but all the text that are in the `ViewControllers` in my language, I will need to translate to English in the new project.

Comment: This will surely work. You need to use `bundle identifier` string to separate code logic for both targets, whereever you want. Both targets can be deployed as two different apps.

Comment: Thanks! How can I rename the whole `Test copy` to `TestTwo`? And what happens to my CocoaPods libraries?